# Is something like Prism INavigationAware Interface for ViewModels in Xamarin.Forms 4 AppShell Navigation?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

In Prism for Xamarin.Forms there is an interface `INavigationAware`. You implement it in the ViewModels (if you want to). There are three methods, `OnNavigatedFrom`, `OnNavigatedTo` and `OnNavigatingTo`. These methods are called by the Prism navigation framework. You can load data, do some logging or cancel the navigation operation.

Now I am using the new Shell Navigation (`AppShell`) in Xamarin.Forms 4.1 without Prism. Is there something equivalent or similar available with Shell Navigation? Is there an adviced pattern to, for example, load some data from a database when the user navigates to the page or to cancel Navigation Operation?

**Edit: I understand Prism does not support Shell Navigation at the moment. What I ask, is to do something similar *without* Prism.**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56793314/4984832

Answer (score 0):

As was provided above. This question has previously been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56793314/4984832

Xamarin.Forms Shell is not currently supported. It is a planned feature in Prism 7.3 and won't start until sometime after some changes from the Xamarin.Forms team are available in an official build. The issue can be tracked here: https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/1809

Comment: I am aware Prism does not support Xamarin.Forms Shell yet, my question was if there is something similar _without_ using Prism, probably out of the box of Shell Navigation.

Comment: The answer is no for the same reason that Prism does not support it. It's not yet extensible.

Comment: You mean Xamarin.Forms Shell is not extensible yet?